# Get the sum of values in a Typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a view component that receives data via an @Input. 
How can a get the sum of values? I tried in constructor and as function, but doesnt seem to work right.

Here is my sample code
Interface and class

```js
interface IChartData {
  date: string;
  dogs: number;
  cats: number;
  total: number;
}

class ChartData implements IChartData {
  constructor(public date: string, public dogs: number, public cats: number, public total: number=0 ){
    this.total = this.dogs + this.cats;
  }

  getTotal() {
    return this.dogs + this.cats;
  }
}
```

My Angular component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'animal-chart',
  templateUrl: 'animal.component.html',
  providers: [ ],
})

export classAnimalChartComponent extends Translation implements OnInit {
  private _data = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});
  values: MaintenanceChartData[] = [];

  constructor(public locale: LocaleService,
              public localization: TranslationService,) {
    super(localization);

  }

  @Input()
  set data(value) {
    // set the latest value for _data BehaviorSubject
    this._data.next(value);
  };

  get data() {
    // get the latest value from _data BehaviorSubject
    return this._data.getValue();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._data
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.values = x['result'];
      });
  }
```

Comment: Define it "doesn't seem to work right."

Comment: What does your Angular component have to do with your chart data?

Answer (score 1):

You need global variable in class (myChartData). Then in the constructor you need to fill it and then return the value from global in the getTotal() function.

```
  interface IChartData {
    date: string;
    dogs: number;
    cats: number;
    total: number;
  }

  class ChartData implements IChartData {
    myChartData: IChartData;
    constructor(public date: string, public dogs: number, public cats: number, public total: number=0 ){
      // this.myChartData["date"] = date;
      // this.myChartData["dogs"] = dogs;
      // this.myChartData["cats"] = cats;
      // this.myChartData["total"] = total;
      this.myChartData = {
        date: date,
        dogs: dogs,
        cats: cats,
        total: total
      }
    }

    getTotal() {
      this.myChartData["total"] = this.myChartData["dogs"] + this.myChartData["cats"];
      return this.myChartData["total"];
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is very confused. You have a class implementing `IChartData` which then also holds an instance of `IChartData`?

Comment: what is the exact problem when you try to get getTotal() ? your code should return the value. You can create angular service to get and set the values. i think i realy do nit understand yiur question.